# Stacking divs based on available space

Tags: javascript, css, math

I've got a collection of divs that are generated, positioned absolutely and adjusted for size by JavaScript based on start and end values.

```js
var posts = [
 {
   start: 50,
    end: 200,
    text: "Lorem ipsum"
  },
 {
   start: 280,
    end: 350,
    text: "dolor"
  },
 {
   start: 140,
    end: 300,
    text: "sit amet"
  },
 {
   start: 440,
    end: 590,
    text: "consectetur"
  },
 {
   start: 460,
    end: 570,
    text: "adipiscing"
  },
 {
   start: 480,
    end: 550,
    text: "elit"
  },
];

$.each(posts, function(i, post){
 var obj = $("<div />");
  
  obj.css({
   left: post.start,
    width: post.end - post.start
  })
  obj.text(post.text);
  
  obj.appendTo("#timeline");
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  height: 60px;
}

.timeline div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 5px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Current</h1>
<div id="timeline" class="timeline"></div>




<h1>Ideal</h1>
                      <!-- Height of the timeline adjusted to make room -->
<div class="timeline" style="height: 170px">
  <div style="left: 50px; width: 150px;">Lorem ipsum</div>
                                       <!-- This one not moved down because
                                       there is still room for it in the
                                       original position -->
  <div style="left: 280px; width: 70px;">dolor</div>
                                         <!-- Element moved down to
                                         since it overlaps two previous ones -->
  <div style="left: 140px; width: 160px; top: 60px;">sit amet</div>
  <div style="left: 440px; width: 150px;">consectetur</div>
                                         <!-- Element moved down -->
  <div style="left: 460px; width: 110px; top: 60px;">adipiscing</div>
                                        <!-- Element moved down even further -->
  <div style="left: 480px; width: 70px; top: 115px;">elit</div>
</div>
```

However, if two or more of these divs have overlapping start and end values, the generated divs will also overlap. Ideally, I'd like to calculate which divs would overlap, and add a `top` value so that each div is fully visible. The element with the larger `start` value should be the one to move down.

How can I figure out which elements overlap, so I can move those down a notch or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat naive approach, which just loops through all the posts, and checks each post against every other post. If it finds they are in the same range, it increased the top value. It only compares posts if they have equal top values as well.

Note the run time of this is O(n^2) which is not great, but for a small amount of post, it should be ok.

```
function detectOverlaps(posts) {
  for (let i=0; i<posts.length; i++) {
    for (let j=0; j<posts.length; j++) {
      if (i == j) continue;
      var post1 = posts[i];
      var post2 = posts[j];
      if (post1.top != post2.top) continue;
      if ((post1.start < post2.end && post1.start > post2.start) ||
          (post1.end > post2.start && post1.end < post2.end)) {
        var post = (post1.start>post2.start) ? post1 : post2;
        if (!post.top) post.top = 0;
        post.top += 60; // Change this by the pixel amount
      }
    }
  }
  return posts;
}
```

[Here is the updated fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/pt8s0qdr/)

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of what has actually been inserted to each line, then you can run a simple check-overlap function to decide whether the next div will fit:

```js
var posts = [
 {
   start: 50,
    end: 200,
    text: "Lorem ipsum"
  },
 {
   start: 280,
    end: 350,
    text: "dolor"
  },
 {
   start: 140,
    end: 300,
    text: "sit amet"
  },
 {
   start: 440,
    end: 590,
    text: "consectetur"
  },
 {
   start: 460,
    end: 570,
    text: "adipiscing"
  },
 {
   start: 480,
    end: 550,
    text: "elit"
  },
];

var lines = [];

$.each(posts, function(i, post){
 var obj = $("<div />");

  var lineNumber = addToLines(lines, post);
  
  if (lineNumber === lines.length) {
    lines.push([post]);
  }
  
  obj.css({
   left: post.start,
    width: post.end - post.start,
    top: 3 + lineNumber * 54
  })
  obj.text(post.text);
  
  obj.appendTo("#timeline");
})

function addToLines(lines, post)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
    if (fitsInLine(lines[i], post)) {
      lines[i].push(post);
      return i;
    }
  };
  
  return i;
}

function fitsInLine(line, postToAdd)
{
  for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++){
    if (overlaps(postToAdd, line[i])) return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

function overlaps(x, y)
{
  if (x.start < y.end && x.start > y.start) return true;
  
  if (x.end < y.end && x.end > y.start) return true;
  
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.timeline {
  margin: 20px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
}

.timeline div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  top: 5px;
  background: darkblue;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
}


h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  margin: 50px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Current</h1>
<div id="timeline" class="timeline"></div>



<h1>Ideal</h1>
                      <!-- Height of the timeline adjusted to make room -->
<div class="timeline" style="height: 170px">
  <div style="left: 50px; width: 150px;">Lorem ipsum</div>
                                       <!-- This one not moved down because
                                       there is still room for it in the
                                       original position -->
  <div style="left: 280px; width: 70px;">dolor</div>
                                         <!-- Element moved down to
                                         since it overlaps two previous ones -->
  <div style="left: 140px; width: 160px; top: 60px;">sit amet</div>
  <div style="left: 440px; width: 150px;">consectetur</div>
                                         <!-- Element moved down -->
  <div style="left: 460px; width: 110px; top: 60px;">adipiscing</div>
                                        <!-- Element moved down even further -->
  <div style="left: 480px; width: 70px; top: 115px;">elit</div>
</div>
```